# Superset Configuring SSO with Active Directory

Tags: single-sign-on, apache-superset

I have superset 1.3.1 installed on a rhel 7.5 server. I would like to set up SSO authorization to the Superset server for Active Directory users. Tell me, please, how to do it correctly?